# Windows 8.1 bootloader recovery

Tags: linux, windows-8, grub, bootloader

I have installed Linux Mint on notebook with Windows 8.1. I didn't install grub on /dev/sda and installed it on /dev/sda5. After booting to Windows I tried to add Linux in Windows bootmenu using EasyBCD. But something went wrong and I could not boot anything. I installed grub to /dev/sda and now I can boot to Linux. When I run command `sudo update-grub2` I see:

```
Found Windows Boot Manager at /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

If I try boot to Windows I see black screen. Is it possible to recover Windows bootloader from Linux? Or maybe I can do something to boot to Windows from grub?

Answer (score 0):

I think that supergrub disk can help you, it is a live distro with a lot of features.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Comment: I tried. There is many options with "Microsoft" label. But when I choose it, it said that "Try boot in UEFI mode". When I boot from usb with linux mint there is 2 options for usb: `UEFI: Sandisk...`
and `Sandisk...`
But when I boot with super grub there is only one option for usb:
`Sandisk...` and I don't know how to boot in UEFI mode